# Android Image ID

Tags: android, kotlin

I am building an Android(Kotlin) app which gets data from an API. Part of that data is an Image or more like a reference to an Image inside the Android app. Sadly Android does not accept names as arguments for images, so I have to send IDs(numbers). The Problem is that these IDs are changing when you add or remove a Image from the Android App and in general they do not seem to be "fixed" or unique.

My questions are:

1. Is there a bullet proof way to reference an Image via Text/Numbers?
2. Do IDs change from phone to phone? (Is ID "213226123" the same Image on every App where the app is installed?)

I could send an Image identifier made by myself and then work with a switch statement to check which image its supposed to be but this makes easy things complicated and would be incredible bad design.

Comment: One would argue that the design is bad. Do you need to have the images embedded into the apk? Or can you fetch them from your server? You can display images from the network using http://square.github.io/picasso/ for example. And your server would just tell you which link to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: For your request there is a solution but you'll have to do some mapping.

Say your API is returning images as a number: e.g.

```
{ 
  ...
  "imageId": 243,
  ... 
}
```

When setting the image, you map the imageId to the id of your drawable

```
imageView.setImageResource(findImageForId(myObject.imageId))

fun findImageForId(imageId: Int) = when(imageId){
    1 -> return R.drawable.imageA
    ...
    243 -> return R.drawable.imageXYZ
    ...
}
```

2. Id's of your drawables are generated at compile time so they won't change in between phones using the same APK. You can't be sure all your users have the same version (e.g. after an update) so you should never use your generated drawable id's to identify images

Comment: Sadly you are right with the problem of the same version. Will try to map over the Apis result, its kinda ugly that I have to call another function when I know which Image is meant. Anyway thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get any resource (including images) id by name with [getIdentifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. Then you can get the resource using the id.

Comment: thanks for the answer, seems that this is a proper way, I will read the docs

Answer (score 2):

You can get the id of your image(s) dynamically calling the `getIdentifier()` method of the `Resources`, like this:

```
val id = context.resources.getIdentifier("my_image", "drawable", context.packageName)
```